# Glassfish 4.1 Deploy Fails - Could not find an implementation of ClassAnalyser

Tags: glassfish, jackson, eclipselink, cdi, glassfish-4.1

Working on a JPA project using Eclipselink 2.5.2 and using Jackson 2.5.1.
EJB's work fine on version 4.0.  Further to installing upgrade to 4.1 I get the following error on deploy;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an implementation of ClassAnalyzer with name CdiInjecteeSkippingClassAnalyzer
```

The full stack trace is;

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
... 59 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
... 61 more
Caused by: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an implementation of ClassAnalyzer with name CdiInjecteeSkippingClassAnalyzer
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:928)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:902)
at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.internal.EjbComponentInterceptor.inject(EjbComponentInterceptor.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2014)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:507)
... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an implementation of ClassAnalyzer with name CdiInjecteeSkippingClassAnalyzer
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAnalyzer(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2249)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getClassAnalyzer(Utilities.java:172)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:927)
... 81 more

2015-04-02T08:56:17.769+0100|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[ie.dcs.bnw.gfserver.config.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet ie.dcs.bnw.gfserver.config.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find an implementation of ClassAnalyzer with name CdiInjecteeSkippingClassAnalyzer
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAnalyzer(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2249)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getClassAnalyzer(Utilities.java:172)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:927)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:902)
at org.glassfish.jersey.gf.ejb.internal.EjbComponentInterceptor.inject(EjbComponentInterceptor.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2014)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:507)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy263.testNominal4Query(Unknown Source)
at ie.dcs.bnw.gfserver.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__CustomerService__Intf____Bean__.testNominal4Query(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I sporadically witness that Exception too. Does the EJB/method that is affected (CustomerService.testNominal4Query?) happen to use any of `@Singleton`, `@Startup`, or `@ExcludeDefaultInterceptors`? Because those annotations seems to be correlated in my case.

Comment: There's a thread on the Jersey mailing list about this missing "ClassAnalyzer with name CdiInjecteeSkippingClassAnalyzer" exception, cf. http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Erratic-missing-quot-CdiInjecteeSkippingClassAnalyzer-quot-Exceptions-td7583446.html. Basically, in that case it is apparently a case of some server initialization not completed yet when a method on an EJB is called.